# Parsing JSON: Stuck in a seemingly easy jq task

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON of this sort:

```
{
  "key1": {
      "unicode": "f26e",
      "label": "pink",
      "free": false
  },
  "key2": {
      "unicode": "b1e3",
      "label": "red",
      "free": true
  },
  "key3": {
      "unicode": "11a2",
      "label": "blue",
      "free": false
  }
  ...
}
```

And I want to extract the pair label/unicode from each inner object. So far I only could get the list of all keys with:

```
jp '. | keys' icons.json
```

Do I have to start drilling from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

`.[] | {unicode,"label": .label}`

produces:

```
{"unicode":"f26e","label":"pink"}
{"unicode":"b1e3","label":"red"}
{"unicode":"11a2","label":"blue"}
```

The "gotcha" here is that "label" is a keyword, and so one cannot write `{label}` as an abbreviation for `{"label":.label}`.

Comment: You made it look super simple, but I spent a couple of hours. Would you mind explaining the command?

Comment: `.[]` can be used to iterate over the values in an array or an object. As the last paragraph implies, `{unicode}` is just an abbreviation for `{"unicode": .unicode}`. With those two insights and the (official) jq tutorial behind you, the simplicity should be easier to appreciate :-)